# calculate the length of a sequence after adding the length of previous sequences

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I want to determine length of individual sequences in a multifasta file. I got this biopython code from the bio manual as:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(str(sys.argv[1]), "fasta"):
 output_line = '%s\t%i' % \
(seq_record.id, len(seq_record))
 print(output_line)
```

My input file is like:

```
>Protein1
MNT
>Protein2
TSMN
>Protein3
TTQRT
```

And the code yields:

```
Protein1        3
Protein2        4
Protein3        5
```

But I want to calculate the length of a sequence after adding the length of previous sequences. It would be like:

```
Protein1        1-3
Protein2        4-7
Protein3        8-12
```

I don't know in which of the above line in the code I need to change to get that output. I'd appreciate any help on this issue, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy just to get the total length:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
total_len = 0
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(str(sys.argv[1]), "fasta"):
    total_len += len(seq_record)
    output_line = '%s\t%i' % (seq_record.id, total_len))
    print(output_line)
```

To get a range:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
cmdargs = str(sys.argv)
total_len = 0
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(str(sys.argv[1]), "fasta"):
    previous_total_len = total_len
    total_len += len(seq_record)
    output_line = '%s\t%i - %i' % (seq_record.id, previous_total_len + 1, total_len)
    print(output_line)
```